# populate select box from MSSQL data with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I've searched and found some answers that are close, but not quite what I need. I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

I have a work assignment that I don't fully know how to do. I have a basic knowledge of PHP and SQL, but a solid understanding of HTML and CSS.

SO, I built a beautiful web form with lots of select boxes. Some will pull data right from a MS SQL database. When submitted, some will push data back into the database. For this question I wan to focus on pulling from the DB.

I did get the PHP page connected to the database, but getting the select boxes to populate is giving me a real hard time. I want to learn how to do this.

My form page is calling a config.php file with the connection info like this:

```
<?php
//Require config file with DB connection details
require_once('config.php');
?>
```

My config file looks like this:

```
<?php
$serverName = "xxxxxxxxx\xxxxxx"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxxxx", "UID"=>"xxxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 echo "Congratulations! Your DB connection has been established.<br />";
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

My page displays the message that the connection is successful. My big question is this, what else to I have to put on my form page to get it to display data in a select box?

Here what i was trying but isnt working...

```
<?php
//Require config file with DB connection details
require_once('config.php');

$result = mssqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Auditors ORDER BY ID");

while($row = mssqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['AuditorName'];
  echo "<br>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And then the select box code:

```
<select name="auditor" id="auditor">
<?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
    <option><?=$row["Auditor"]?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and maybe post an example of what WILL work? Once I get this part figured out, I have several other select boxes to apply it to, so this will be a great help.

The above code gets me a blank page with only my successful DB connection message. My whole form disappears and there is no error message.

Thanks in advance for your time,
Jason

Comment: I guess its mssql_query

Comment: @CodingAnt - Does this look right? `$result = mssqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Auditors ORDER BY ID");`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using both while and foreach you can make it work by bringing your while loop down

```
<select>
<?php
while($row = mssqli_fetch_array($result))
{  
   echo '<option>' . $row["Auditor"] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>

<?php
   mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, and forgive my noobness... so, now I have: 

`<?php
require_once('config.php');

$result = mssql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Auditors ORDER BY ID");

$rows = array();
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
?>`
 
and also 

`<select name="auditor" id="auditor">
 <?php foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo '<option>' . $row["Auditor"] . '</option>';
  }
 </select>` 

does it look right?

Comment: No, not working. I must be missing something. I'll try to display everything here. You might need to copy it into an editor and take a look.

`</head>

<body>
<?php
require_once('config.php');

$result = mssql_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Auditors ORDER BY ID");

$rows = array();
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
?>
`

Comment: And the select box code:
`
         <select name="auditor" id="auditor">
     <?php foreach ($rows as $row) {
                  echo '<option>' . $row["Auditor"] . '</option>';
     }
                 ?>
              </select>`

Comment: Can you do this, print_r($rows); anywhere before the select box and see what is the output

Comment: change mssqli_fetch_array to mssql_fetch_array